# Show mp4 and 3gp files for selection in Android

Tags: android

I have an app where i need to select video files of .3gp and .mp4 format only. I use the following code. It shows only 3gp files , how do i show mp4 files also?

```
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.putExtra("only3gp", true);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you go about finding the extensions of file manually like this,

```
Intent intent= new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri filetype= Uri.parse("file://" + file.getPath());
        String filename=file.getName();
if(filename.endsWith(".mp4")||filename.endsWith(".3gp"))
 {
            intent.setDataAndType(filetype, "video/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: The thing is I am relying on MediaStore to display the list of all 3gp files. I also want the same for mp4 mimetype.